# Jenkins returns 403 forbidden when slaves try to contact it

Tags: java, ubuntu, jenkins

I installed jenkins on Ubuntu and when I try to run the agents to create nodes I get back an IOException:

```
Failing to obtain http://<Master IP>:8090/computer/<Slave IP>/slave-agent.jnlp
java.io.IOException: Failed to load http://<Master IP>:8090/computer/<Slave IP>/slave-agent.jnlp: 403 Forbidden
        at hudson.remoting.Launcher.parseJnlpArguments(Launcher.java:499)
        at hudson.remoting.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:325)
        at hudson.remoting.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:283)
```

As far as I can tell iptables isn't up and I can't find the reason behind it.

Comment: Can this thread help you: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-16273

Comment: tried. didn't help, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Using this option:    -jnlpCredentials USER:PASSWORD

USER is your Jenkins user ID

Comment: PASSWORD - it may be the Jenkins user's password, or it may be the user's "API token" that can be generated for each user under their Jenkins account's 'Configure' page.

Answer (score 0):

In latest version the option is -auth USER:PASSWORD

USER - username of the jenkins master
PASSWORD - that user's password (Or API key setup from account details)

Answer (score 0):

Error :
Failed to obtain https://jenkins.site/manage/computer/ValidateNode/jenkins-agent.jnlp
java.io.IOException: Failed to load https://jenkins.site/manage/computer/ValidateNode/jenkins-agent.jnlp: 403 null

Fix :

1. Navigate to https://jenkins.site/manage/configureSecurity/
2. Anonymous user need to have Read, connect & Discover permission

Comment: It's not advisable to allow unauthenticated (anonymous) read access.  And it is worse to let an agent register without authentication.  These actions are not required for agents to register and should not be used.